# tfs Run multiple test during daily build in tfsbuild.proj

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2008

I have one build definition (TFS 2008), with two solutions in it:

TFSBuild.proj:

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../ProdigyUtils/Development/ProdigyUtils.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../ProdigyUtils/Release 01.00/ProdigyUtils.sln">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties></Properties>
</SolutionToBuild>
```

These 2 solutions have there own .vsmdi file for the daily unit tests.

If I put one of the .vsmdi files into the tfsbuild.proj file:

```
<MetaDataFile Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../ProdigyUtils/Development/ProdigyUtils.vsmdi">
    <TestList>Daily Debug</TestList>
</MetaDataFile>
```

The tests of the SECOND solution is executed by the daily build. Yes, NOT the .vsmdi file of "Development" is used, but the .vsmdi file of "Release 01.00"

Is there a way to run both test .vsmdi files in the daily build?